# Load balancing one process per user

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, kubernetes, shiny, architecture

I am running a web app (on an Ubuntu 20.04 VPS) that is single threaded and quite computationally expensive; an R Shiny application. Therefore, I need a load balancer that routes each single user/session to a separate process. I need this to happen dynamically, so that I only have processes running that are actually being used at the time, and a new process is started when a new user visits the URL.

At the moment I use Shiny Server Pro for this load balancing, but this product is going in maintenance moment in probably a year.

I have looked at multiple possible alternatives, from a simple nginx configuration to a more complex kubernetes solution, but have not found exactly what I need. It seems like such a trivial requirement, that I get the feeling I am looking in the wrong direction.

Does anybody know how to do this, and is able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at the `shinyproxy` https://www.shinyproxy.io/. you can always spin out multiple shinyapps and control it yourself depending how many users are using the app

Comment: HI, thanks for your answer, however shinyproxy is rather slow in starting up processes which makes it not a viable alternative for us.. Is this not  a problem that you have arrived at when using shinyproxy?

Comment: Im not using `shinyproxy` I would normally offload heavy processes somewhere else or spin up multiple `shiny` instances and control the redirects with a master shiny app